# apt-get upgrade fails because of max recursion on udev

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie, udev

When i´m doing a apt-get upgrade on my debian jessie ( a vserver from hetzner) machine, i get an error on upgrading the udev package.

The Error Output starts with this:

```
addgroup: Die Gruppe »input« existiert bereits als Systemgruppe. Programmende.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S100startencryptd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'startencryptd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rmnologin if started
insserv: There is a loop between service 0startencryptd and mountnfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 7
insserv:  loop involving service rpcbind at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service 0startencryptd and mountall if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 9
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service 0startencryptd and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and udev if     started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service 0startencryptd if started
insserv: Starting startencryptd depends on rmnologin and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
```

The last error comes 98 more times and ends with:

```
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
```

And then the last output is:

```
insserv:  loop involving service mdadm at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 6
insserv: There is a loop between service rmnologin and mountall-bootclean if started
insserv: There is a loop between service 0startencryptd and mdadm-raid if started
insserv:  loop involving service mdadm-raid at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service 0startencryptd and mountdevsubfs if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service 0startencryptd at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes udev (--configure):
```

Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: Fix the LSB of `0startencryptd`

Comment: That went well.